# Oracle Managed DataAccess connection object is keeping the connection open

Tags: c#, oracle, ado.net, system.data.oracleclient, oracle.manageddataaccess

I'm using `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess` Nuget package version `18.3.0`. I tried many things. I tried to dispose everything I can think of, even oracle parameters objects. And wrapped everything inside a `using` block but to no avail. The only thing that actually worked for me is that the commented line `OracleConnection.ClearPool(oracle);`. Is this a bug, or some configuration related issue, or am I misunderstand things here? Also, I tried to remove the reference of `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess` and replaced it with a reference to `System.Data.OracleClient` and that actually worked for me. It automatically closed the connection, so no connection left with "In-Active" status. The code below I moved it into a simple, single button, Windows Forms application to make 100% sure nothing is interfering and the problem still occurring.

```
using (var oracle = new OracleConnection("Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=myhost)(PORT=SomePortHere))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=SHARED)(SERVICE_NAME=anotherHost)))", new OracleCredential(userName,password)))
                {
                    oracle.Open();
                    using (var command = new OracleCommand())
                    {
                        var query = "SELECT x from y where z=:param1";
                        command.Connection = oracle;
                        command.CommandText = query;
                        command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                        var param1 = new OracleParameter(":param1", xyz);
                        command.Parameters.Add(param1);
                        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            if (reader.Read())
                            {
                                //read the data from the reader
                            }
                        }
                        param1.Dispose();
                    }
                    //If this line is commented, there will be a connection left open, with InActive status
                    //OracleConnection.ClearPool(oracle);
                }
                password.Dispose();
                return myData;
```

And this is an image to show the opened connection through `Toad`.
[image: Oracle Connection issue]
Of course, for each click to that button, the code above will execute and a new session will remain open, until what you see in the image.
The name "TheTesterOfAllTests.exe" is the Windows Forms app.
Is this a configuration problem?
Is there any way to solve this issue other than using `ClearPool` method? Because it affects the performance of the app.
*P.S. The application that is originally using the code above is a `WCF Service` that is consumed by a Web application.*
*P.S. 2 There is some kind of memory leakage, with each click to that button the memory usage increases*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem is in the way internally oracle creates connection, since for each newly created `OracleConnection` object, a new Connection is added to the Connection pool. I counted `91` connection entry in the connection pool. 
The solution was to use one `OracleConnection` instance for each request "Per Request Scope". I implemented that by using a simple generic `IDatabase<TConnection>` interface with one `TConnection GetConnection<TConnection>()` method and of course for each method that will be called on that same request's instance, a pair of Open/Close call will take place so we don't keep the connection open the whole time.

Regarding the memory leak, I'm still not able to `100%` confirm this, but when I used the `Oracle.DataAccess.Client` library instead of `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess` the memory usage reduced dramatically. So, I switched back to `Oracle.DataAccess.Client`.
**P.S.** *I will update this answer in case of new information regarding these two issues, and contributions are very welcome, maybe I misunderstand something regarding how Oracle deals with the database connection.*

Comment: Please, post your code here, I have a similar problem.

Comment: @fsbflavio Nothing special, just a simple interface `IDatabase<T>` that returns `OracleConnection` object. The idea behind it is to store the instance of type `IDatabase<T>` globally and pass to other consumers by constructors. The consumers are responsible to open/close the connection by calling `IDatabase<T>.Open()` and `IDatabase<T>.Close()`. Of course you can achieve the same by using any kind of `DIC` that allows you to scope object lifetime `PerRequest`.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem.
I solved it by changing the initialization of the OracleConnection.

from

```
var con = new OracleConnection(
    "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=myhost)(PORT=SomePortHere))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=SHARED)(SERVICE_NAME=anotherHost)))",
    new OracleCredential(userName,password));
```

to

```
var con = new OracleConnection(
    "USER ID=myuser;PASSWORD=mypwd;Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=myhost)(PORT=SomePortHere))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=SHARED)(SERVICE_NAME=anotherHost)))");
```

To me, this different behavior looks like a bug.

As a result, i can no longer use OracleCredential and must store the password as a string. That's okay for me.

remark: [SecureString shouldn't be used](https://github.com/dotnet/platform-compat/blob/master/docs/DE0001.md)